# Cloud storage image Not APPLY in a determinated webpage

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone use Google Cloud Image Storage? We use it on our website and on worpress and it works very well all over the web.

But we want you NOT to apply only on a certain web page, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Could you be more precise? What do want to not apply?

Answer (score 0):

**Cloud Storage allows world-wide storage and retrieval of any amount of data at any time**, as mentioned in the [Google's official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/). Additionally, keep in mind that GCS is a central integrated repository that can be used for media content storage and delivery for multiple destinations, which means that it is not tied to serve only certain web page.

Based on this, if you are having issues to access to your files located in Cloud Storage, I suggest you to validate if you are setting the correct [access permissions to your buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions), as well as verify that you are using a valid [authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) to access to your **GCS** service.

Finally, you can take a look on the [Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage) and [Understanding Google Cloud Storage Features](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/understanding-storage-features) guides in case you are working with GCS for AppEngine Standard/Flex.